# How to have datepicker set default year?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using bootstrap datepicker and I only show the years. When I load the page, I would like to set a default year, tried the following but the current year (2018) is hightlited instead.

```
$('#sandbox-container div').datepicker({
  format: "yyyy",
  viewMode: "years", 
  minViewMode: "years",
  updateViewDate: false,
  changeYear: true,
  defaultDate: '2014'
});
```

Thing is this is an Edit page, so the year is coming from the db, therefore I need to be able to set a default year as per the value I am getting from the db.

Comment: Have you tried `startDate` instead of `defaultDate`?  https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#startdate

Comment: Or even `defaultViewDate` https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#defaultviewdate

Comment: @mrrogers as per the code above, if I do `startDate: '2014'` I still get current year, not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn same thing, if I use the code in the question and do `defaultViewDate: '2014'` I still get current year highlighted

Comment: the doc says it should be an object `{year: '2014'}`

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn nope solved it, had `updateViewDate: false`, changing it into `updateViewDate: true`, works. Posting my own answer

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn by what I'm seeing as it is working, both using an object or a string works

Comment: Then that must be compatible with `format`

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn probably using the object is better tho, as I am not sure how it would handle it if we do `22` as a year instead of a 4 digits, updating my answer as it is far better to use object, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to change `updateViewDate: false` into `updateViewDate: true,` so:

```
$('#sandbox-container div').datepicker({
  format: "yyyy",
  viewMode: "years", 
  minViewMode: "years",
  updateViewDate: true,
  changeYear: true,
  defaultViewDate: {year: '2014'}
});
```